# Force gnu-parallel to treat replacement string as command

Tags: gpu, gnu-parallel

I want to pass a file containing a list of commands to gnu-parallel while using replacement strings (e.g.: `{%}`).

Unfortunately, if replacement strings are used, gnu-parallel interprets the commands in the file as arguments to `/bin/bash`.

Here's what I want to do:

```
parallel -j 8 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$(({%} - 1)) {}' < commands.txt
```

where the content of `commands.txt` is:

```
/path/to/binary -arg1 a -arg2 1.0
/path/to/binary -arg1 a -arg2 1.1
...
/path/to/binary -arg1 z -arg2 9.9
```

However, this raises the following error:

```
/bin/bash: /path/to/binary -arg1 a -arg2 1.0: command not found
```

I was hoping GNU Parallel to run:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 /path/to/binary -arg1 a -arg2 1.0
```

The purpose of the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` is to make each process run on a different GPU (by default all processes run on the same GPU). If I didn't need `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, the following code would work perfectly:

```
parallel -j 8 < commands.txt
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: What command were you hoping **GNU Parallel** would run?

Comment: So what is CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES for?

Comment: All processes run on the same GPU if I don't specify a different value of CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES for each process.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want an environment variable set differently for each instance. I didn't pick that up from your question.

Comment: I think if I use --colsep ' ' it will work, I'm about to find out.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I expected GNU Parallel to run `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 /path/to/binary -arg1 a -arg2 1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `--colsep` may work sometimes, it is not always the correct choice. This will create the files `abc` and `def`:

```
echo 'touch abc\ def' | parallel -v --colsep ' ' A=B {}
```

Normally it will be better to de-quote the expression using `eval`:

```
echo 'touch abc\ def' | parallel -v eval A=B {}
```

So:

```
parallel -j 8 'eval CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$(({%} - 1)) {}' < commands.txt
```

If you use `$(({%} - 1))` a lot, consider making your own replacement string:

```
echo '--rpl {%-1}\ $_=slot()-1' >> ~/.parallel/config
parallel -j 8 'eval CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES={%-1} {}' < commands.txt
```

Or even:

```
echo '--rpl '"'"'{CUDA} $_="CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=".(slot()-1)'"'" >> .parallel/config
parallel -j 8 'eval {CUDA} {}' < commands.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `--colsep ' '` does the trick:

```
parallel -j 8 --colsep ' ' 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$(({%} - 1)) {}' < commands.txt
```